# using $lookup inside nested array of object, created multiple record in response, mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Please see this mongoplayground :: [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v--0qxO4RtW)

Here I have used $lookup to populate `user` field inside `history array`. But I am getting 2 different objects in response. How can Ii push both users inside original history array?

history.user is a string field here.

Please help.

Comment: thanks for highlighting, its corrected now.

Comment: @cmgchess, I want 'history' to remain as an Array, and user field inside that should be populated from users table. in the result you can see that, history become an object not array. Sorry if my explanation is not clear.

Comment: probably this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/lGDYsflGNWj

Comment: Exactly this sir, just one request, by any mean is it possible to not use $unwind, so that original fields are not lost?

Comment: how about this 
https://mongoplayground.net/p/TL9gemKtKuF

Comment: Yes sir, this works, plz post in answers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do [with unwinding and grouping](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lGDYsflGNWj) as well but a downside is that you need to use a bunch of `$first` in the group stage to not lose fields. So if there are a lot of fields in the main doc it can get a bit repetitive

An approach without unwinding

1. convert the string `history.user` to ObjectID
2. Lookup and get the associated users in to a `users` field
3. `$map` through  the history array and for each user search through the newly added `users` field and take the first element matched from the `$filter`
4. Finally remove the `users` field

```js
db.approval.aggregate([
  { $match: {} },
  {
    $addFields: {
      history: {
        $map: {
          input: "$history",
          in: { $mergeObjects: [ "$$this", { user: { $toObjectId: "$$this.user" } } ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "history.user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "users"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      history: {
        $map: {
          input: "$history",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                user: {
                  $first: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$users",
                      as: "i",
                      cond: { $eq: [ "$$i._id", "$$this.user" ] }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "users" }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TL9gemKtKuF)